# Data option change isn't picked by jquery

Tags: javascript, jquery

I've got div like this :

```
<div id="something-1" data-options='{"pause":"YES","delete":"NO", "kill":"NO"}'></div>
```

What I got going on is some ajax request and changes the data options like this :

```
$('#something-1' + item.id).attr("data-options", '{"pause":"YES","delete":"YES", "kill":"NO"}');
```

When I inspect with firebug I can see changed data options in html.

Then I have this "test" function which I trigger from firebug to see if the data has changed after the ajax update :

```
(function() {
        window.checkChanges = checkChanges;
        function checkChanges(id) {
        var dataOptions = $("#" + id).data('options');

        for(var index in dataOptions) {
            console.log(index,dataOptions[index]);
        };
        }
    })();
```

But for some reason data options are the same before and after ajax request. I would need to somehow incorporate live function into this? or something else, but I don't have idea what? any suggestions?

**Edit**

Ajax requests changes delete to `YES`

Comment: why don't you try those function from your js itself instead of trying from firbug console.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Remove the quotes wrapping the object you are trying to set to the `options` so you are passing an object not a string to `data`

```
$(selector).attr("data-options", {"pause":"YES","delete":"YES", "kill":"NO"});
```

DEMO: http://jsfiddle.net/8A3LE/

Another way to change one value only

```
$(selector).data('options').delete='YES'
```

Answer (score 1):

Is it possible you mixed up the ID of the selected div? In your fake ajax-request you add an item.id after "something" which is not present in your checking. Then it works just fine.

http://jsfiddle.net/EVyVT/

charlietfl noted that you can ommit the quotes around the object but I think it works with quotes, too.